# Webpack requires files dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to require files dynamically with Webpack like so:

```
this.svg = require(`resources/assets/images/svg/${this.name}.svg`);
```

Of course because this code only runs in `NodeJS`, Webpack has no clue what `this.name` is and creates a context.

With the context it grabs all the files from that particular directory and jams them into my javascript bundle. I do not want all of the files from this directory though I just want the ones want this exact name.

Since this can't be achieved at runtime is there a way to provide a static list of files which Webpack can run through?

Sort of like a forEach with require.